# Wordpress: installed theme doesn't show up

Tags: wordpress

Newbie on wordpress here. I just installed wordpress on my PC (ubuntu 12.04) directory '/var/www/wp'.  I can see the themes in `http://localhost/wp/wp-admin/themes.php`.

Now I purchased a new theme xyz.zip and unzipped it in directory `/var/www/wp/wp-content/themes`, so the directory `/var/www/wp/wp-content/themes` has a new directory called xyz (in addition to the existing themes).

The problem is, when I refresh the web page `http://localhost/wp/wp-admin/themes.php`,  I don't see the new theme.

Any idea why?  Thanks.

Comment: Check if there's a style.css file in the root of the directory. You should check what the readme files say, or find installing instructions.

Comment: Thanks @harrypujols for the quick reply, yes, the file `style.css` is there.  Don't see an installation guide for the theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duh! Turned out it's permission problem on the directory xyz.  Once I fixed the permission, it works ok.